# setState doesn't work when function passed through props is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I have a React component (`App.js`) that does ajax requests (via axios). The values of parameters passed through these requests are taken from inputs fields manipulated by the user. Based on the response it updates its state.

```
sendValue(value) {
  const url = `${myURl}/c${value}\r`;
  axios.get(url)
        .then(res=>{
              this.setState({
                       data:res.data
              })
         })
         .catch(err => {
            console.log('err', err);
         })  
}
```

And then in the return statement this function is passed as a prop to a child component:

```
<Child sendValue={this.sendValue}>
```

The child component (`Child.js`) has a couple of input fields. This child component has its own state. When the input fields are changed,  the values will be passed to the axios function through the props.

```
handleChange(e) {
      const { value } = e.target;
      this.setState({ input: value }, console.log('state', this.state));
      this.props.sendValue(`${value}\r`);
}
```

The actual input element looks like this:

```
<input
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

If I leave out this line `this.props.sendValue(${value}\r);` the state gets updated and the value of the input fields change (the console.log as a callback function proves this, and also that the actual value of the input field changes). 
But when I leave it in, nothing changes, the state never gets updated, console.log never gets called.

Why?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you bind sendValue to where it s defined?

Comment: yah, I bind it in the constructor via `this.sendValue = this.sendValue.bind(this);`

Comment: any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: Did you bind handleChange??

Comment: I did bind handleChange and no errors in the dev console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Child component would be like below, the problem is in the Child's constructor, I guess you initialize the state there.

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 'init-value' // or null
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
   ....
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ....
      <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      ....
    );
  }
}
```

`this.props.sendValue` is a function passed from (belongs to) Parent Component and it includes `setState` statement. If it was triggered, Parent Component re-rendering would happen.

In the `handleChange(e)` function, after

`this.setState({ input: value }, console.log('state', this.state));`

which changes the Child's state

`` this.props.sendValue(`${value}\r`); ``

re-render the Parent Component, and of course, Child is involved in.
So the `state` value is initialized again, and it seems like nothing happens.

Maybe you would like to using props from Parent Component to give value to `state.value`.

Comment: ahhh, okk, I see. Yes, that would work, but then I have to put all the states for everything into the Parent Component, which makes the state for the Parent Component very big, especially if the project becomes very big. Is that how you are supposed to do?

Comment: @Tom, it's all about the design pattern, if your Parent component is fat but reasonable for maintaining, I think it's just ok. Or, just lead in [redux](https://redux.js.org/), which borns for this.